# Trying to Register Data From Database to Login Site, Unable to Produce

Tags: spring-boot, maven, thymeleaf, h2

Cannot figure out how to get my Login Success page to return the information of the user that has logged in to the site. This might be an issue with user logins themselves, but I'll post my code in case.

This is what is returned. The only correct value is password. Everything else should have info in it.
Using Thymeleaf, h2 database, and SpringBootJPA.

```
Login Success!
Name:null null
E-mail:
Password:password
Subject:
```

login_form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Valencia College Login Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
          crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style type="text/css">
        label {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
            margin: 5px;
            text-align: left;
        }
        input[type=text], input[type=password], select {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 200px;
        }
        input[type=checkbox] {
            margin-right: 20px;
        }
        input[type=dropdown] {
            width: 100px;
            display: inline-block;
        }
        button {
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 8px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <h1>Valencia College Login</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/login}" method="post" th:object="${student}">

        <div class="border border-secondary p-3 rounded">
            <p>Sign in to Valencia College</p>
            <label>Username:</label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" />
            <br/>

            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" />
            <br/>

            <label>Subject:</label>
            <select class="dropdown" id="dropDownList" th:width="100px">
            <option value="0">Select Course</option>
            <option th:each="subject : ${listSubject}" th:value="${subject}" th:text="${subject}" />
            </select>
            <br/>
            <p>
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" />&nbsp;Remember Me
            </p>
            <button type="submit">Login</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

login_success.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
  <title>Login Success</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    span {
      display: inline-block;
      width: 200px;
      text-align: left;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div type="center">
  <h2>Login Success!</h2>
  <span>Name:</span><span th:text="${student.firstName + ' ' + student.lastName}"></span><br/>
  <span>E-mail:</span><span th:text="${student.email}"></span><br/>
  <span>Password:</span><span th:text="${student.password}"></span><br/>
  <span>Subject:</span><span th:text="${student.subject}"></span><br/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

FinalProjectAppApplication.java

```
package com.finalmv.finalprojectapp;

import com.finalmv.finalprojectapp.model.Student;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@SpringBootApplication
public class FinalProjectAppApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinalProjectAppApplication.class, args);
    }


    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(StudentRepository repository) {
        return (args -> {
              insertJavaAdvocates(repository);
              System.out.println(repository.findAll());
        //    System.out.println(repository.findStudentBySubjectContaining("CAC"));
        });
    }
    private void insertJavaAdvocates(StudentRepository repository) {
        repository.save(new Student("mvictor8", "password","Mervens", "Victor", "mvictor8", "CAC 1015"));
        repository.save(new Student("jteddy1", "password","Jason", "Teddy", "jteddy1", "APR 2035"));
        repository.save(new Student("jdonelle9", "password","Jemmy", "Donelle", "jdonelle9", "CAC 1015"));
        repository.save(new Student("ccarter3", "password","Christine", "Carter", "ccarter3", "MAC 1123"));
        repository.save(new Student("tnoa8", "password","Tanya", "Noa", "tnoa8", "MAC 1123"));
        repository.save(new Student("cadria7", "password","Chalice", "Adria","cadria7", "APR 2035"));
        repository.save(new Student("sregina4", "password","Scott", "Regina","sregina4", "TET 1560"));
        repository.save(new Student("ylilian5", "password","Yvon", "Lilian","ylilian5", "MAC 1123"));
        repository.save(new Student("rmason2", "password","Rolland", "Mason","rmason2", "APR 2035"));
        repository.save(new Student("calbaldric2", "password","Christian", "Al Baldric","calbaldric2", "CAC 1015"));


    }
}
```

StudentRepository.java

```
package com.finalmv.finalprojectapp;

import com.finalmv.finalprojectapp.model.Student;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface StudentRepository extends CrudRepository<Student, Long> {
    List<Student> findStudentBySubjectContaining(String str);
}
```

FinalProjectController.java

```
package com.finalmv.finalprojectapp.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.finalmv.finalprojectapp.model.Student;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;


@Controller
public class FinalProjectController {
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        Student student = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student", student);

        List<String> listSubject = Arrays.asList("CAC 1015", "APR 2035", "MAC 1123", "TET 1560");
        model.addAttribute("listSubject", listSubject);

        return "login_form";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayLogin(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("student", new Student());
        List<String> listSubject = new ArrayList<String>();
        listSubject.add("CAC 1015");
        listSubject.add("APR 2035");
        listSubject.add("MAC 1123");
        listSubject.add("TET 1560");
        model.addAttribute("listSubject", listSubject);
        return "login_form";
    }

    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String submitForm(@ModelAttribute(name = "student") Student student, Model m) {
        String username = student.getUsername();
        String password = student.getPassword();
        if (username.equals(student.getUsername()) && password.equals(student.getPassword())) {
            m.addAttribute("username", username);
            m.addAttribute("password", password);
            System.out.println(student);
            return "login_success";
        }
        return "login_form";
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:student;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=mv
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
spring.h2.console.settings.trace=false
spring.h2.console.settings.web-allow-others=false
server.error.include-exception=true
server.error.include-stacktrace=always
```

I had a multitude of errors getting it here. I've to rename the constructors but I return null. It seems to not be able to read the database. It could also be that my database is not being publically hosted or stored, which prevents any possible read entries.

Comment: In `submitForm` function you should also add `student` as an attribute i.e. `m.addAttribute("student", student);` . Does `System.out.println(student);` print all details you expect to read in success page like name & subject?